# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable (random module)

Tags: python, random, module

From last two days I have been getting continually a error in my code for importing random module "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/git/random.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\git\random.py", line 3, in <module>
    if random.random() < 0.5:
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Could someone provide me a solution for my code?

Comment: Your own file is called random.py, that's interfering with the standard library module import.